# Close script popup from vb.net

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I'm developing a win32 application in vb.net that needs to read info from some websites, using the "WebBrowser" control.

The problem is that sometimes, and randomly, some popups appear while the service is reading a web site, all I need is to close, or "accept" this popup so the service can continue his work.

Hope anyone can help me.

EDIT: I can just disabled the script errors:

```
WebBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = True
```

This just doesn't show the error, but doesn't solve the problem, still working on it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that using a webbrowser control is the best way of doing this. If you are reading a web page then you can use the following code to read the html and then parse it yourself (this will avoid any popups)

```
Public Shared Function GetPageAsString(ByVal address As Uri) As String
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest
    Try
        request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(address), HttpWebRequest)
        Using response As HttpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
            Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
                Return reader.ReadToEnd
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Return ""
    End Try
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim url as string = "http://www.bbc.co.uk"
Dim webContent As String = GetPageAsString(New Uri(url))
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, but the program is huge and it's all done with the webbrowser control, so, i'm not changing it unless it's extremely imperative.

I've tried with the "NewWindow" event from the WebBrowser control, but it doesn't trigger when the popup shows up...

Thanks anyway :P